# How to create user auth without closing the current firebase session

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to make a system where the administrator can create user auth from an email. I have developed as the documentation says but the current session is closed. I only want to create the auth to get the uid and then create a user in the database with the data I want to store.

This is what I have:

```
var email = emailInput.value;
var password = "Abcd1234";
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((userCredential) => {
    var user = userCredential.user;
    //user.uid contains the id I want to create the instance on ref usuarios
    database.ref("usuarios/"+ user.uid).set({...});
});
```

**Edit:**

[image: frontend JS]

[image: Cloud Function]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create new users using client SDK. By that I mean a user creating new users as required. You need to use Firebase Admin SDK (which must be in a secure server environment - like Firebase [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)).

You can write a cloud function like this:

```
exports.createNewUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (isAdmin(context.auth.uid)) {
    return admin.auth().createUser({
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password,
      displayName: data.name
    }).then((userRecord) => {
      // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
      console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
      return { uid: userRecord.uid }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
      return { error: "Something went wrong" }
    });
  }
  return {error: "unauthorized" }
})
```

Now there are multiple ways you could verify that the user who is calling this function is an admin. First one would be using [Firebase Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) which are somewhat like roles you assign to users. Another option would be storing UID of using in database and checking the UID exists in admin node of db. Just make sure only you can edit that part of the database.

To call the function from client:

```
const createNewUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('createNewUser');
createNewUser({ name: "test", email: "test@test.test", password: "122345678" })
  .then((result) => {
    // Read result of the Cloud Function.
    var response = result.data;
  });
```

Comment: And how I can call this function from a javascript file?

Comment: @EmiliBellotPulido I have updated the answer. You can [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function) for more details.

Comment: Nice, and the result.data will contain the uid?

Comment: @EmiliBellotPulido it'll contain what ever you return from the function. You can do this `return { uid: userRecord.uid }` to return the UID :D

Comment: The code works -> The user is created in firebase Authentication, but the result is giving null

Comment: @EmiliBellotPulido can you make sure you have added the return keyword? You must also add return before admin.auth() line. Also make sure you have added a return statement out of if block to return error. I've updated the code for same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232342/discussion-between-emili-bellot-pulido-and-dharmaraj).