# Create account using flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

is it possible like I have to entity like user and admin and i have login with admin account and want to create user account using flutter firebase

Comment: If I have login with admin and create User account it will remove my admin credential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase client-side SDKs are not designed for building administrative functionality like what you're doing. For example, they can have only one current users, and creating a new user indeed kicks out any previously signed in user. You're also likely to run into rate-limits with this approach, as it simply goes against the logic that the API/SDK was designed for.

The main options you have:

1. Let each user create their own account

   This is the preferred approach from the Firebase API perspective, so I recommend looking into why you want someone else to create the accounts. The most common use-cases for wanting this are that you actually are trying to **invite** users (in which case it's better to send them a dynamic link) or to approve users (in which case you're better off creating an allow-list).
2. Use the Admin SDK to create the accounts, and expose this as a custom API to your client

   The Firebase Admin SDKs *are* able to create user accounts (and with much higher quota), but can't be used in client-side code. So you'll typically want to create a custom API (for example with Cloud Run or Cloud Functions) that you can then call from your client-side code. Make sure to validate whether the user is authorized to make the call though.
3. Use an additional `FirebaseApp` instance in the client to create the user

   You *can* create an additional `FirebaseApp` instance with the same configuration data, get the auth instance from that, and then use that to create a new user without kicking out the existing admin. I don't recommend doing this anymore these days, as you're still more likely to run into rate limits with it, but on an API level it is possible.

Also see:

- [Firebase kicks out current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user)
- [How to avoid being signed in automatically when a new user is created using firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65967246/how-to-avoid-being-signed-in-automatically-when-a-new-user-is-created-using-fire)
- [How to create user auth without closing the current firebase session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67516996/how-to-create-user-auth-without-closing-the-current-firebase-session)